# Randomly select points in a feature layer

Tags: python, arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api, arcgis-notebook

Context: I'm working on AGOL notebooks

I have a feature layer (points). So, I'd like to randomly select several points based on the value in one of the columns ('level_' column).

For instance, I'd like to randomly select 16 points of level 1 and 10 of level 2, then I will use the result to plan a route using plan_routes().   The thing is that I don't want the two results separate because I need them to be in the same feature so I can use them as input for planning the routes.

In the code below I queried the feature layer to get only the points of level 1 & 2.

```
# query parcels - level 1 & 2
m_levels = test.query(where="level_= '1' OR level_='2'")
m_levels
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will select a user defined number of level 1 and level 2 records at random from the dataset, just update the num_level1 and num_level2 variables. I have commented the code for ease of use. Make sure to add your item id and the layer index. You could turn the random selection for each into a function.

```
from arcgis import GIS
import random

agol = GIS("home")

item = agol.content.get("***item_id***")

## update the index here to that of the layer you require
lyr = item.layers[0]

num_level1 = 16
num_level2 = 10

################################################################
## lets get random level 1 features ############################

## get all feature with level 1, return only IDs
level1 = lyr.query(where="level_ = 1", return_ids_only=True)

## extract ids from dictionary to list
l1_objids = level1["objectIds"]

## get the highest index in the list
level1_upper = len(l1_objids) - 1

## we will populate this with the amount of objectids
## stated in num_level1
random_level1 = []

## while the list doesnt meet thenumber of random entries
while len(random_level1) < num_level1:
    ## get a random index
    random_index = random.randint(0, level1_upper)
    ## get the onjectid at that index
    objectid = l1_objids[random_index]
    ## and if its not already in the list then add it
    if objectid not in random_level1:
        random_level1.append(objectid)

##print(random_level1)

################################################################
## lets get random level 2 features ############################
level2 = lyr.query(where="level_ = 2", return_ids_only=True)

l2_objids = level1["objectIds"]

level2_upper = len(l2_objids) - 1

random_level2 = []

while len(random_level2) < num_level2:
    random_index = random.randint(0, level2_upper)
    objectid = l2_objids[random_index]
    if objectid not in random_level2:
        random_level2.append(objectid)

##print(random_level2)

################################################################
## combine the lists
all_objids = random_level1 + random_level2
## convert items to string
all_objids = [str(objid) for objid in all_objids]

##print(all_objids)

## create a query string to return only objectids in all_objids
query_exp = "OBJECTID IN ('{0}')".format("','".join(all_objids))

## query out this records only
records = lyr.query(where=query_exp)

print(len(records))
```